# Prestashop FrontController::$context is protected property when create a order

Tags: php, prestashop, cart, prestashop-1.5

My module I'm try to make a order from cart.

In my modules controller file I'm calling `validateOrder`

```
 PaymentModule::validateOrder((int)$urbCart->id, $order_status, $order_total, "urb-it", NULL, array(), (int)$currency->id, false, $urbCart->secure_key);
```

to create an order. However I got error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access protected property 'UrbitOrderCompleteModuleFrontController::$context in /opt/webapp/urbit/classes/PaymentModule.php on line 171'

The payment module error is happen in (line 171) is below

```
if (!isset($this->context)) {
    $this->context = Context::getContext();
}
```

Why that context is say as protected property? How can I create order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`validateOrder()` is not a static method so in your module controller call it like this:

```
$this->module->validateOrder((int)$urbCart->id, $order_status, $order_total, "urb-it", NULL, array(), (int)$currency->id, false, $urbCart->secure_key);
```

Any controller which extends either `ModuleFrontController` or `ModuleAdminController` have a property `module` object of the module which uses the controller.

Edit:

Module class must extend `PaymentModule` in order to use `validateOrder` method.

Comment: I've tried that already but it says `Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Urbit::validateOrder()` 
I cant understand why it says like that.

My controller is like below
`class UrbitOrderCompleteModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController {
public function postProcess() { ....`

Comment: @miuranga Are you extending your module class from `PaymentModule` and not `Module`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you saying (I'm new to prestashop)
In my controller I'm extending `ModuleFrontController`.
However I've tried with module class `class UrbitPaymentOrder extends PaymentModule`  and call `PaymentModule::validateOrder` inside that but same results :(

Comment: @miuranga Again, you cannot call `PaymentModule::validateOrder` since it is not static method. In controllers you call it as `$this->module->validateOrder`, in module you call it as `$this->validateOrder`. First, your module needs to extend `PaymentModule`. Second, your module controller class names need to follow naming convention which is `ModulenameFilenameModuleFrontController` so if for example you have controller filename as `payment.php` the controller class name has to be `UrbitPaymentOrderPaymentModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController`.

Comment: Seems My  naming convention is correct. file name is `OrderComplete.php` and module name is `Urbit` so class name is `UrbitOrderCompleteModuleFrontController` . 

In the controller file I call it as `$this->module->validateOrder`  but it not worked.  
Then I created a new class in module directory `extends PaymentModule` like below.

`class UrbitPaymentOrder extends PaymentModule { `

inside that I call `$this->validateOrder(...` like you said but it gives below error `Call to undefined method UrbitOrderCompleteModuleFrontController::validateOrder()`

Comment: @miuranga Do not create new module class but your current module `Urbit` needs to extend `PaymentModule`.

Comment: Im already extending `CarrierModule` in `Urbit`.  is that the reason ?

Comment: @miuranga Yes, that is it. If `Urbit` module is `CarrierModule` you cannot validate orders since `CarrierModule` is not meant to process payments/order validations. Create a new separate payment module with controllers to use order validations.

Comment: you are correct. that is the issue. after extending `PaymentModule` the issue has fixed. However is there any way to use both `CarrierModule` and `PaymentModule` in one module because my module has separate functionality for carrier.

PS. please update your answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: PHP doesn't support multiple inheritance so no you can't use both and I don't see the point of using both in one module. One carrier module and another payment module is the way to do it since they're separate processes that handle different things.